# code::blocks does not autocomplete keywords from "cstdlib"

Tags: c++, autocomplete, include, codeblocks

I have this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void printRandomDice(int amount) {
    srand(time(0));

    for (int i; i < amount; i++) {
        cout << (rand() % 6) + 1 << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    printRandomDice(5);
}
```

It works perfectly but the thing is that when I was writing "rand()" and "srand(time(0))", it didn't show autocomplete options for those functions. I really want to knw how I can get this fixed, or if it is even possible to do so.

Code Completion Settings:
[image: Code Completion Settings]

Answer (score 0):

Check settings:

`Settings` > `Editor` > `General Settings` > `Editor Settings` > `Code` `Completion` > `Check [Code Completion]`.

And Disable smart sense.
With `SmartSense` enabled (default) code completion work partially.

Comment: It doesn't seem I have the option to disable SmartSense. I'll send you an image on private chat

Comment: I just realized you cant DM people so I will just edit my answer.

Comment: In my experience, code blocks breaks easily. Maybe, try re-installing it or try another IDE. And I dont know why there isn't option for smart sense, it used to be there as far as I remember. Maybe, re-installing it will work.